# Apply colour mask overlay to image that honours transparency using HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, filter, colors

I'm creating an arcade game using Javascript that draws to a 2D Canvas context.

To simulate 'pain' in sprites that have been shot I want to have them flash orange.

I currently draw the image to the canvas using `ctx.drawImage()`.

Rather than create more artwork to apply the 'in pain' effect I'd like to use Javascript. 
I've researched `globalCompositeOperation` but as yet can't find a solution.

Here is the original image drawn to the canvas over the scrolling background graphic:
[image]

In theory I'd like to then apply a rectangular orange area using `fillRect()`:

[image]

The effect that I'm after is this:
[image]

Not this:

[image]

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Comment: Can you include the code you have used to draw and colour in the sprite, please?

Comment: Your original ship image also have this land background ?? Otherwise, the easiest in this case would be to use an offscreen canvas, where you'll do the blending, only on the ship. You'd then just have to draw this offscreen canvas on the main one.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I did. Cheers.